# Import Android "Gridlayout library project" directly into my project

Tags: android, library-project, android-gridlayout

i already found out how to use the Gridlayout for Android 4.0 Devices. I downloaded the support library, imported it as a library project and then i referenced it as a library in my own project.
But i want to have the library directly in my own project. I already copied the files of the libs folder in my own libs folder. And i also copied the attrs.xml and dimens.xml into my own project. Then i added both jar files to my build-path.
Eclipse itself gives me no error, but the Android layout editor can't render my layouts anymore, because of some "can't find, etc" problems (i writing this not from my office, so i sadly can't post the exact error message, but i will do tomorrow).

I really need everything in one project. 
Did i forget something? Is it even possible? Because i haven't found any "Grid Layout Support Library sample" where someone merged everything in one project.

I hope you understand my problem, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
This is what my layout editor says:

> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
>   The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
>   See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

And here my to error log messages:

> general.xml: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
>
> android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout failed to instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`right click` your `project->properties->java build path->order` and export
where tick mark all option.

I hope this will solve your problem.