# Eclipse and Android SL GridLayout not working together - "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout could not be instantiated"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

I'm new to Android development, so it's possible this is a simple question. Apologies if it is - I spent quite some time searching but couldn't find anything that worked.

I'm trying to use a GridLayout in my project, but ideally with the Android Support Library so I can target lower versions of the API. When I drag a GridLayout into the graphical layout designer, a message pops up asking explaining I need a compatibility library for API versions older than 14, and asks if I want to install this library. I hit "Install" and let Eclipse do its thing, but an error shows up in the Eclipse graphical layout designer:
`The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
See the Error Log ( Window > Show View) for more details.` ([Screenshot](http://oi50.tinypic.com/14b448o.jpg))

From the error log,
`android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout failed to instantiate.` [Here's the stack trace](http://pastebin.com/A563yhH1)

My search for this error turned up [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773981/eclipse-giving-an-error-of-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-failed-to-instan), which seemed promising; I checked my Java, Eclipse and ADT versions but all seem to be reasonably up-to-date (Java 7 update 17, Eclipse Juno release, ADT 21.1). With the update checks out of the way, I looked at how that SO user had his project set up: a library project for the gridlayout, a project reference to this library in the main project, and the gridlayout jar copied into the main project's libs folder. Following the Eclipse "install compatibility library" message, a gridlayout library project had already been created for me, but the project reference had not been set up and the gridlayout jar hadn't been copied. I did both these things but still the GridLayout fails to instantiate.

I continued searching and found [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468606/intellij-and-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout). Despite that thread not using Eclipse, I attempted to translate the answer into the Eclipse equivalent, which was roughly the same as given by the thread above. (Copy the gridlayout jar to the project's libs folder, create a library project from gridlayout, and add a project reference to that library project from within the main project.) I also verified that the gridlayout jar is on the main project's build path. ([Screenshot](http://oi49.tinypic.com/w8xmiu.jpg))

I also attempted to follow the instructions in the relevant [Styling Android blogpost](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1395), but that's even worse: when I try to drag a GridLayout into my project, it throws two errors, a `RelativeLayoutRule.onDropped() failed: 
java.lang.NullPointerException` with [this stack trace](http://pastebin.com/f96Fatcp) and an `Initializing project state` with [this stack trace](http://pastebin.com/JqmakyeA). Based on the IOException mentioned in the "Initializing project state" stack trace, I speculated the problem might be my install location for the Android SDK: `%APPDATA%\Local\Android`. I finally tried uninstalling the SDK and reinstalling it to `%PROGRAMFILES%\Android` but without any luck.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. If anyone could give me a pointer in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: refer second answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376151/import-android-gridlayout-library-project-directly-into-my-project

Comment: Are you suggesting I roll my own GridLayout equivalent? That's definitely an interesting idea, but I'm not sure I know enough about Droid coding yet to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
File->Import->Existing Android code into workspace
Specify android-sdk-[platform]/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout

You need to import the GridLayout project as an Android library project for it to work.

Comment: I did try that several times, but with no luck. Probably should've mentioned that in my OP.

Comment: Finally got it working - it was a combination of factors, I think. I ended up reinstalling the Android SDK to a path without spaces, downgraded my JDK from version 7 to version 6, and directly imported the GridLayout project like you suggested. Giving you the answer because I wasn't sure whether I needed to use the support library's .jar or the project before your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i meant clear your build path...

Try this:

right click your project->properties->java build path->order and export where tick mark all option

Comment: I just created a new project, dragged a GridLayout into it, and let Eclipse install the compatibility library. I checked that the auto-generated gridlayout project was marked as a library - all good. My project references the gridlayout project in Properties->Android - all good. gridlayout_v7.jar is on the build path in Properties->Java Build Path ->Libraries->Android Dependencies - all good. In Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export, everything is checked - all good. But for some reason I'm still getting the "could not be instantiated" error. Any other ideas?

Comment: then try another idea in link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376151/import-android-gridlayout-library-project-directly-into-my-project